# Getting intger from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, int

I'm trying to get a variable intger from another activity

My codes:

```
------- Activity --------

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Question.this, Answer.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", position);

    startActivityForResult(intent, position);
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {

    int pos = ------- "I'm trying to get the position in this activity or pos in the other activity." ------- 

    if(pref.getBoolean("answered"+pos, false)){
           ------ Do Something --------
    }

}
```

This is in another activity, I'm trying to get position from the first activity or pos from this activity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
pos = (int) intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
```

I'm trying to get the int in pos which is in onActivityResult

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I fixed it by adding

```
onActivityResult(position, position, intent);
```

Comment: yes your code is right 
pos = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
you get pos by this code

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `intent.getIntExtra("id", 0)`?

Comment: @DivyangMetalia I've tried, didn't work

Comment: @StavL change you line 

pos = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is method For called `getIntExtra()` for receiving `int` values from intent..

you should probably use that instead of using `getStringExtra()`...

**because `getStringExtra()` wont convert **`int`** to **`String`**** and your variable will be null...

So you should probably try following code...

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.getExtras() != null)
{
    pos = (int) intent.getIntExtra("id",0); // zero( 0 ) is default value... 
}
```

**Edit:**

If you are getting value in **`OnActivityResult()`**
you should probably try...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {

    i = i.getData();
    int pos = i.getIntExtra("id",0);
    }

}
```

Comment: This works fine, however I'm trying to get the int in pos which is in onActivityResult

Comment: I fixed it by adding

    onActivityResult(position, position, intent);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**In first Activity**

```
String pos = String.valueOf(position);
intent.putExtra("id", pos);
```

**In secong Activity**

```
String id= intent.getStringExtra("id");
int pos= Integer.parseInt(id);
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: Krupa, I think he should do String id= intent.getIntExtra("id",0);

Comment: I'm trying to get pos from position or from pos in the other activity, this didn't work

Comment: This works fine, however I'm trying to get the int in pos which is in onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

getIntent() will give you intent for whole activity. but in your case you want value from the intent which is as one parameter in onActivityResult method.

so do

```
pos = (int) i.getExtras().getInt("id");
```

as intent variable is i as per your method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i)
```

Comment: Thank you! this works fine, however it doesn't when I do "if(pref.getBoolean("answered"+pos, false))" it doesn't do anything

Comment: you did not write anything for pref. share code for it. Also what error you are getting on this if condition, share your logcat.

Comment: There is no error, the only thing wrong is that it doesn't do what I want it to do if its true.

Comment: As i said share code then only we will be able to tell you anything. code should include declaration for pref too